# checking database for existing patient and then adding if does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have created a page whereby a mysql query checks if a patient already exists in the database, if the patient doesn't exist then the following code should add them to the database

```
 <?php
    include("includes/staffmenu.php");
    include("includes/staffsession.php");
    @require_once("includes/dbconfig.inc");

    $firstname=$_POST["pfname"];
    $middlename=$_POST["pmname"];
    $surname=$_POST["psname"];
    $nat=$_POST["pnat"];
    $DOB=$_POST["pdob"];
    $pemail=$_POST["pemail"];
    $add1=$_POST["padd1"];
    $add2=$_POST["padd2"];
    $add3=$_POST["padd3"];
    $postcode=$_POST["ppcode"];
    $telephone=$_POST["pphone"];

        $pcheck=mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM patient 
        WHERE 
        Patient_First_Name='$firstname' AND Patient_Middle_Name='$middlename' AND Patient_Surname='$surname' AND Patient_National_Insurance_No='$nat' 
        AND Patient_DOB='DOB' AND Patient_Address_Line_1='$add1' AND Patient_Address_Line_2='$add2' AND Patient_Address_Line_3='$add3' AND Patient_Postcode='$postcode'");
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_row($pcheck);
            if($myrow)
                    {   echo "This Patient already exists.<br><br> Please press the back button on your browser or the backspace button on your keyboard to go back";

                    }
            else
                    {   mysql_query("INSERT INTO patient (Patient_First_Name,Patient_Middle_Name,Patient_Surname,Patient_National_Insurance_No,Patient_DOB,Patient_Email,Patient_Address_Line_1,Patient_Address_Line_2,Patient_Address_Line_3,Patient_Postcode,Patient_Phone_No  ) 
                        VALUES('$firstname','$middlename','$surname','$nat','$DOB','$pemail','$add1','$add2','$add3','$postcode','$telephone')") or die (mysql_error());
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<p>Success! The Patient has been added to the database
                        </p>";
                    }   
    ?>
```

The problem is that even if the patient already exists it keeps on adding a new one... Could someone please advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: i hope this code is no where near my medical records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `$` when searching for DOB.

`Patient_DOB='$DOB'`

Also, please note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: thank you, I can't believe I've spent half a day trying to work out what's wrong with my code!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
Patient_DOB='DOB'
```

to

```
Patient_DOB='$DOB'
```